# Grafana Singlestat null map with color?

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I use grafana to show the device status in last 5 min.

If the device not send data to influxdb, I assume that device is offline.

Query `select last(value) from heartbeat where SN='****' and time > now() - 5m`

I created a Singlestat with value text map

- 0 -> Ready
- 1 -> Processing
- null -> offline

Use the Thresholds I am able to set the color for `0` and `1`.

However, is not able to set the color for `null` value.

Is someone know how to set the color for `null` value(no result in influxdb query)?

Answer (score 1):

Null is not a valid field value and is unsupported. There are only 4 field types supported, int64, float64, bool and string.

Not possible. You can use Singlestat panels in particular they are useful as they treat  null as zero, otherwise there's no way to color a panel with a null result. [Doc](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/951)

Also check the [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/write_protocols/line_protocol_reference/) for valid syntax for each of those field types.

Comment: Yes, I am not say insert `null` into influxdb. The `null` is that if the query return `no result`, the grafana think it is return `null`. And in this case, not possible to set the color.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Grafana doesn't support `null` mapping at the moment, there's [an issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/8404) for that.